# Ubuntu 13.10 Unity Sound Indicator - Won't display changes

Tags: unity, sound, indicator

So, interesting problem.

**What I have done:**

I click the sound indicator and adjust the volume with no problems. I can use the sound keys on my keyboard and it works without an issue. I can adjust and manipulate the sound in any fashion and it works. However, the indicator itself (speaker looking icon) will not show changes. Such as, if I press mute, it will indeed mute, but the icon will not show an "X", but the sound level will be all the way down, will indicate a red-X Speaker notification.

The slider will change based on how I adjust the sound, but the speaker icon will not lose it's  "rings" (little vertical lines to the right of speaker icon).

**What I know**

I know there has been a recognized bug in Lubuntu XFCE that the indicator does not work, but the issues I am having are not like theirs. My sound operates as it should, the Unity Indicator is not.

**What I have done**

I have tried some quick fixes I have seen to no avail they are:

editing `usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service` and changing

```
"Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service"
```

to

```
"Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service"
```

**THE ABOVE DID NOT WORK FOR ME**

Just wanted to indicate in case someone is blindly changing files thinking I found a fix.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

To make things more interesting, the indicator works 100% as it should on the login screen but not once I log in.

Output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`:

```
ii  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1                  12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2         amd64        Typelib files for libappindicator3-1.
ii  gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1                       12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1         amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status - bindings
ii  indicator-application                     12.10.1daily13.01.25-0ubuntu1           amd64        Application Indicators
ii  indicator-appmenu                         13.01.0+13.10.20130930-0ubuntu1         amd64        Indicator for application menus.
ii  indicator-bluetooth                       0.0.6+13.10.20131016-0ubuntu1           amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  indicator-cpufreq                         0.2.2-0ubuntu1                          all          CPU frequency scaling indicator
ii  indicator-datetime                        13.10.0+13.10.20131016.2-0ubuntu1       amd64        Simple clock
ii  indicator-keyboard                        0.0.0+13.10.20131010.1-0ubuntu1         amd64        Keyboard indicator
ii  indicator-messages                        13.10.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1         amd64        indicator that collects messages that need a response
ii  indicator-multiload                       0.3-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Graphical system load indicator for CPU, ram, etc.
ii  indicator-power                           12.10.6+13.10.20131008-0ubuntu1         amd64        Indicator showing power state.
ii  indicator-printers                        0.1.7daily13.03.01-0ubuntu1             amd64        indicator showing active print jobs
ii  indicator-session                         12.10.5+13.10.20131004-0ubuntu1         amd64        indicator showing session management, status and user switching
ii  indicator-sound                           12.10.2+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1         amd64        System sound indicator.
ii  indicator-sound-gtk2                      12.10.0.1-0ubuntu2                      amd64        System sound indicator.
ii  indicator-sync                            12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1         amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status
ii  indicator-sysmonitor                      0.4.3                                   all          System Monitor Indicator
rc  indicator-weather                         13.7.1                                  all          indicator that displays weather information
ii  libappindicator3-1                        12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2         amd64        Application Indicators
ii  libindicator3-7                           12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu1         amd64        panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libindicator7                             12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu1         amd64        panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libsync-menu1:amd64                       12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1         amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status - libraries
ii  my-weather-indicator                      0.6.5-0extras13.04.2                    all          Get weather information for your town with My-Weather-Indicator
ii  sni-qt:amd64                              0.2.6-0ubuntu1                          amd64        indicator support for Qt
ii  telepathy-indicator                       0.3.1daily13.06.19-0ubuntu1             amd64        Desktop service to integrate Telepathy with the messaging menu.
```

Comment: This time try to change your sound using commands and check whether your icon vertical line changes or not. To decrease the volume by 25% execute this :`amixer -q sset Master 25%-`. Execute  2-3 times same command when volume is full(100%). Also to increase the volume by 25% execute this: `amixer -q sset Master 25%+`

Comment: @SauravKumar Same results, sound does change, verticle lines/speaker icon do not change.

Comment: Ok, try to re-configure once by: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure indicator-sound` and logout/login or restart. If it still doesn't help then once try to re-install by: `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-sound` and again logout/login or restart. Reply..

Comment: Now I have no sound indicator what-so-ever even after reinstalling...

EDIT:

Restarted, now all it shows in the grayed out muted icon

Comment: EDIT 2:
Logged in and out, once again missing sound icon...

Comment: I'm Sorry! Something weird happened!! I don't know why is this happened with you. Try to execute these commands hope it'll help you: `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-sound indicator-sound-gtk2` , `sudo dpkg-reconfigure indicator-sound indicator-sound-gtk2` and `sudo update-initramfs -u` Then logout/login or restart. Reply..

Comment: Still don't have a sound indicator now..

Comment: Have you executed the complete command I mentioned..! Because you replied so fast I don't guess you executed all again!!

Comment: I am on this page awaiting your response sir. I have entered all of the commands you have offered and have had no success. Please don't doubt my ability to perform the actions you have offered.

Comment: ha ha ha.. Sorry if I ever doubt your ability! and please don't call me Sir, I'm just a Ubuntu user like you. When you increase/decrease sound by keys, does it work?

Comment: The sound does change, as I have already mentioned, and the notification does change, however the icon does not change. I am also still missing the sound icon.

Comment: Are other indicators in its place or some other are also missing? Edit your question and post the output of this command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`

Comment: Others are in it's place I suppose. It's as if it was never there in the first place, all of the indicators shifter over.

Comment: Please give me some time to review the output..

Comment: Let me post my answer, since it would not be possible to post in comment.

Comment: Ok, it seems as though the indicator works as it should on the login screen but not once logged in.

Comment: This should be submited as a bug in Launchpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED!**

I had found a solution to the problem. I had to reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio and it corrected all of my problems. A detailed explanation of how to do this can be found here:

http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: I was thinking that there is a problem in the indicator applet. Good to know finally you did it. Although I recommend you to mention the basic steps needed. It will help on the case when the link will be delete or broken. :)